# Is it possible to batch updates in Sequel?

Tags: sql, ruby, batch-file, sequel

Is it possible to make many updates in a single call using [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/)?

For instance, making about 200 updates could take several minutes on my server, but if I forge a single SQL query it runs in a matter of seconds. I wonder if Sequel could be used to forge that SQL query or even better, do the whole operation one shot by itself.

Comment: Yes, but it depends on what exactly you're attempting to do, and what RDBMS you're running on.  Please provide more information so we can advise you better.

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL, and I want Sequel to issue a single query for multiple updates, as I'm able to do in plain SQL.

Answer (score 5):

The solution I've come across involves the update_sql method. Instead of doing the operation itself, it output raw SQL queries. To batch multiple updates, just join these with ; in between, call the run method with the resulting string and you're all set.

The batching solution is WAY faster than multiple updates.

Comment: This solution is only faster than 'multiple updates' in that you're only making one actual connection/trip to the database for the entire set of updates, as opposed to one-per.  Please note that some frameworks perform this sort of behaviour automatically - they'll hold the updates in memory until the transaction is committed.  Also, you _may_ be able to receive still greater benefits, if multiple statements can be re-written to _one_ statement.

Comment: That may work in your case, but not all Sequel adapters support multiple queries in Database#run.  Sequel actually does not provide an adapter-independent method that accepts multiple queries in a single string (some adapters will work with such a string, others will not).

Comment: For the mysql2 driver, you have to use { flags: ::Mysql2::Client::MULTI_STATEMENTS } as option when connecting

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Datset#import` http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Dataset.html#method-i-import
"Inserts multiple records into the associated table. This method can be used to efficiently insert a large number of records into a table in a single query if the database supports it. Inserts are automatically wrapped in a transaction."

here's an example of how to use it:

```
DB = Sequel.connect(...)
DB[:movies].import([:id, :director, :title, :year], [[1, "Orson Welles", "Citizen Kane", 1941],[2, "Robert Wiene", "Cabinet of Dr. Caligari, The", 1920]])
```

Answer (score -2):

`Dataset#update` doesn't work for you?

http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Dataset.html#method-i-update